# Proving HK is a subgroup of G through the canonical homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $\;K\lhd G\;
$ and $H<G$. I need to show that $HK=\{ hk:k\in K, h\in H\}$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ and $K.$ To show this lets define the canonical surjective homomorphism: $$ cl: G \rightarrow G/K.$$ I am wondering if the following is true: $ cl^{-1}\circ cl(H)=\{ g \in G:gK \in \{hK:h\in H\}\}=HK.$ As a matter of fact, if it were true, then: since $cl(H)$ is a subgroup of $G/K$ it follows that $cl^{-1}\circ cl(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$ (by assuming that $cl^{-1}$ is also a morphism). Thus $HK<G.$

1. According to definition, $cl(H)=HK$, where $HK$ is to be understood as a subgroup of $G/K $ whose elements are equivalent classes of the form $hK.$ Am i correct ?
2. By writing $ cl^{-1}\circ cl(H)=HK$ the result looks to be the same but the interpretation is different: $HK$ is a product of two subgroups of which one is normal and thus it is a subgroup of $G.$ Am i again correct ?
3. Given $cl: G \rightarrow G/K,  $we know that $|$im$(cl(G)|=|G/K|$ divides $|G|.$ Does this hold also for subgroups, i.e. can we write $|$im$(cl(H)|=|HK|$ divides $|H|$, where $HK$ is the subgroup of $G/K ?$
4. To show that $HK$ is the smallest subgroup containing $H$ and $K,$ let $S$ be a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ and $K.$ I need to show that $HK \subseteq S. $ To do this i need to define $S$. Can somebody offer a suggestion ?

I will higly appreciate any answer to these questions.

Comment: It seems to be you **already** assume $\;HK\;$ is a subgroup (which is true, of course), and you only need to prove it is the minimal such one containing $\;H,\,K\;$ , am I right? But I'd say this follows almost immediately from the definition, as any subgroup containing both $\;H,\,K\;$ must contain all their products and thus any element of the form $\;hk,\,h\in H,\,k\in K\;$ , so I don't understand why the long journey above...

Comment: Thanks. By considering the products, how do you formally see and prove that $HN$ is minimal ? Do you have a comment on the point 3 ?

Comment: I think I just did that in my above comment: any product of two element in $\;HK\;$ must be in *any* subgroup containing $\;H,\,K\;$ , so $\;HK\;$ is the minimal such one...

Comment: As for the long journey, it was merely done for the purpose of understanding what $cl^{-1} \circ  cl(H) $ means, which was not clear to me. To prove that $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$, the simplest way is to apply the ''group test''

Comment: You talk and write as if every mathematician in the world uses the same names that you do. First, what is a "class morphism" is something that I don't know. I **think** you mean the canonical projection homomorphism. Next, what "groups test" you mean is, again, something I don't know. I know the theorem that says that if $\;H,\,K\;$ are subgroups of a group, then $\;HK\;$ is a subgroup iff $\;HK=KH\;$ ....which, btw, is a very nice and useful exercise in basic group theory.

Comment: I am sorry for the terminology. By the class morphism i actually ment the canonical surjective homomorphism. Because it essentialy assigns the equivalence class to each element of $G$, one encounters sometimes the notion of class homomorphism. Under the ''group test'' i meant the basic criteria of proving a set is a subgroup: for $ k,l \in H, kl^{-1}\in H.$

Comment: Ok, I supposed that. Observe that it seems to be much easier with the theorem I mentioned, in particular if you try to prove it assuming one of the subgroups $\;H,\,K\;$ is normal...

Answer (score 0):

Let me begin by addressing things that don't seem to be correct and answering your questions.

Firstly $cl^{-1}$ is not a homomorphism it is not even a map from $G/K$ to $G$, it is a map from $P(G/K)$ to $P(G)$ -- where P(X) denotes the power set of $X$. However, this map does send subgroups to subgroups so that your observation $cl^{-1}(cl(H))=HK$ implies that $HK$ is a subgroup.

Secondly there seems to be no value in confusing $HK$ with $\{hK\,|\, h \in H\}$ in 1.

It is true that $cl^{-1}(cl(H))=HK$ in 2. I not sure why you are asking if this is true since you seem to ,very nearly at least, prove it in the paragraph before your questions. Just observe that $gK \in \{hK\,|\, h \in h\}$ is equivalent to $g = hk$ for some $k$ in $K$.

Avoiding your strange notation, it is true that $|cl(H)|$ divides $|H|$ in 3, but it is probably worth knowing that in fact $H/H\cap K \cong cl(H)$. (Combining this with the fact that $HK/K \cong cl(H)$ one obtains the diamond isomorphism theorem.)

You don't need to define $S$ in 4 to show what you desire. To do so prove that $cl^{-1}(cl(S))=SK=S$ and hence that $HK=cl^{-1}(cl(H))\subseteq cl^{-1}(cl(S))=S$ (since both direct and inverse image preserve inclusions).